# How to determine if the series $\sum \frac{2+\sin n}{5^n}$ is convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I have:

the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2+\sin n)}{5^n} $.

I have split this up into $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2}{5^n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n}{5^n}$. I know the first part is convergent by using geometric, but I am not sure how to approach the second part.
 Please help, thank you!

Comment: Splitting turns out to be harmless, since one can prove that the second series converges. However, it is not a good idea. Definitely easier is comparison with $\sum_1^\infty \frac{3}{5^n}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to show convergence/divergence of a series.  Try the [ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), the [root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test), the [comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_test), or the [integral test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) just to name a few.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_series#Convergence_tests) or [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/Series_Special.aspx) for a more thorough listing of tests for convergence.

In this particular case, the comparison test will be best.  It may help to note that $-1 \leq \sin(n) \leq 1$ so that $1 \leq 2 + \sin(n) \leq 3$.

Comment: @littleO.  It will be easiest here by far. I was providing other tests as the OP seemed to be asking a general question about determining convergence.

Comment: can you be a little more specific in explaining this? i have trouble figuring out which test i have to use

Comment: @JadenQ: On what specifically would like me to elaborate?

Comment: i need help on figuring out the whole series, like how should i approach each part to know if they are either converge or diverge

Comment: @JadenQ: This is too general a question to answer (and perhaps there is no general answer).  In short, it's just practice.  We can see that the denominator grows very quickly, and the numerator is bounded between $1$ and $3$.  Thus, we can compare the series to $\sum \frac{c}{5^n}$.

Comment: You could also find the limit of the second part by noting that $\sin n =\Im{e^{i n}}$, to obtain that $\Im{\sum_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{i n}}{5^n}}=\frac{5 \sin 1}{26-10 \cos 1}$. The first sum is easy ...