# Is this series convergent or not?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The series is :$$\sum_ {n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n }{ 5^n} $$

I am not sure  how to determine if this series is convergent or not. Can someone show me how?

Thanks

Comment: This seems the same question as your previous post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231935/how-to-determine-if-a-series-is-convergent-or-divergent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |\frac{\sin n}{5^n}| \le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{5^n}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{5})^n=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{5}}=\frac{5}{4}$

Comment: Using the formula for the geometric series, we can actually, compute the sum:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}{5^n}
&=\mathrm{Im}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e^{in}}{5^n}\right)\\
&=\mathrm{Im}\left(\frac1{1-e^i/5}\right)\\
&=\mathrm{Im}\left(\frac5{5-e^i}\frac{5-e^{-i}}{5-e^{-i}}\right)\\
&=\mathrm{Im}\left(\frac{25-5e^{-i}}{26-10\cos(1)}\right)\\
&=\frac{5\sin(1)}{26-10\cos(1)}\\
&\stackrel.=0.20427050707618
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4):

We have $|\sin n|\le 1$. Now **compare** with $\sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{5^n}$.

We conclude that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|\sin n|}{5^n}$$
converges. Thus the original series **converges absolutely** and therefore converges.

Comment: Not that it really matters, but the sum actually starts at $n = 0$

Comment: @jak: It certainly doesn't matter, but one might as well use the same beginning as the OP. Thanks!

Comment: Glad someone mentioned that AC $\implies$ C theorem. It's a handy tool.

Answer (score 2):

This series is majorized by $5^{-n}$, i.e.
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left\vert \frac{\sin n}{5^n} \right\vert \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{5^n},$$
and this latter series converges as a geometric series. So our original series converges by comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum range for $\sin(n)$ is $1$, so focus on $\frac{1}{5^n}$. If you take the limit of $\frac{1}{5^n}$ as $n$ goes to infinity, it converges to $0$ because the denominator gets larger and larger as it $n$ goes to infinity.